# how does magento URL access work

Tags: magento, url-routing

Hi i wanted to create a custom form to get input from the user, i can access the form from the url :

```
http://localhost/website/index.php/contest
```

but when i uploaded it to a server which has multiple website setup in the magento, i could not access the form like i used to on local server.

http://www.website.org/index.php/contest

i am stumped , i hit a wall i googled, i just don't know what to look for , any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanking anyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

Magento routing is a sort of big topic to cover in a single Stack Overflow answer.  You can read about the basics of [setting up a controller here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world), and the [probably in too much depth routing process here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch).

That said, here's some general debugging tips.

1. Can Magento see the module your controller is a part of?  If not, you're probably missing your file in `app/etc/modules`.  (look at the module list in `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Module Output)
2. If your module is installed, Magento probably can't find your controller class. Eitehr because it's not there, of you have a case sensitivity issue.  Add some temporary debugging code to the `_validateControllerClassName` function to determine why Magento can't find your controller.

You can find the `_validateControllerClassName` function here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
protected function _validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $controllerFileName = $this->getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller);
    if (!$this->validateControllerFileName($controllerFileName)) {
        return false;
    }

    $controllerClassName = $this->getControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
    if (!$controllerClassName) {
        return false;
    }

    // include controller file if needed
    if (!$this->_includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $controllerClassName;
}
```

Some `var_dump`s before the `return false` clauses should tell you why Magento can't find and/or include your controller class file.